# bayesian terminology for fixed and random effects

Tags: bayesian, terminology

What is the Bayesian terminology for
- fixed effect
- random effect
- least squares mean ?

Or is it OK to use the frequentist terminology?

Answer (score 3):

The distinction made between fixed and random effects is that there is additional structure assumed on the random effects. In Bayesian Statistics, all model parameters are random variables, so using that terminology is confusing. In my opinion, it is clearer to refer to the "random" effects as being modeled hierarchically, e.g. following a normal distribution with some mean and variance.